# Firebase notification not showing properly in android app when app is in background?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the below code for showing a notification.
when I trigger a notification from the console. If the app is in the foreground. I am getting customize notification properly.

```
if (remoteMessage == null)
            return;

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            handleNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
                handleDataMessage(json);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private void handleNotification(String message) {
        sendNotification(message);
    }

    private void handleDataMessage(JSONObject json) {

        try {
            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
            String message = data.getString("message");
            sendNotification(message);
        } catch (JSONException ignored) {
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    }


    public void sendNotification(String message) {
            NotiManager.createNotification(getApplicationContext());
    }
```

Comment: You would need to send a high priority FCM notification in order to receive it even if the app is in Doze mode.

Comment: I am pushing notification from the console.
If the app is in the background I want data payload but I am getting notification payload.